# Remap keyboard with scancode map for disable alt+ctr+del

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I have an application to run on a dedicated kiosk. I want to  disable any key on Windows7.

I want to block Alt+Ctr+Del, that users can't shutdown the system.

I want to disable Alt , Ctrl keys that users can't use Alt+Ctrl+Del, I use this `Scancode Map`

```
REGEDIT5 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode  Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,5b,e0,00,00,5c,e0,00,00,5d,e0,00,00, 44,00,00,00,1d,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,1d,e0,00,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

But don't work for me!!!

How to use scancode map for disable alt+ctr+del?

Comment: Presumably this is the site you've been using so far: http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk ? Can you confirm you've rebooted the computer since updating the registry, and disabled the login screen (which requires ctrl+alt+del) as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308226 ?

Comment: Thanks, I use this link and change version to 5, then rebooted my computer but don't work for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Solution

There are multiple issues in your `.reg` file:

1. `REGEDIT5` is not a valid identifier; use `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` instead.
2. The first line of the file is reserved for the registry editor version and [should be followed by a blank line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/en-us).
3. You put at an extra space between `Scancode` and `Map`.
4. Each comma-separated hexadecimal value should not carry extra spaces.

Here's the fixed, working version:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,5b,e0,00,00,5c,e0,00,00,5d,e0,00,00,44,00,00,00,1d,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,1d,e0,00,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

As per the [article linked by tenorkev](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk), these are the keys which will be disabled:

```
5b e0    Left Windows Key
5c e0    Right Windows Key
5d e0    Windows Menu Key
44 00    F10
1d 00    Left Ctrl
38 00    Left Alt
1d e0    Right Ctrl
38 e0    Right Alt
```

Make sure to restart afterwards in order to apply the changes. As an alternative you might want to use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to disable or remap any key.

### Further reading

- [How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/en-us)

Comment: What is the type of key here- string, binary, DWORD, QWORD?

Comment: Use binary. For google sleuths out there on Mac trying to swap LAlt and LWin, here is my binary: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 38 00 5B E0 5B E0 38 00 00 00 00 00