# Remap Keys - no software

Tags: keyboard, windows-registry, vbscript, remapping

I need to swap/remap the location of the ' (apostrophe & quote key) and the ; (semi colon & colon key). I find it greatly increases typing efficiency.

I need to do this without installing any 3rd part software as the security policy of my company blocks any 3rd party apps. Using Windows 7.

Would need to this via VBScript or edit the Registry please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remap keyboard with scancode map for disable alt+ctr+del](http://superuser.com/questions/700110/remap-keyboard-with-scancode-map-for-disable-altctrdel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this registry. Logout or reboot for it to take effect.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,27,00,28,00,28,00,27,00,00,00,00,00
```